# Highcharts with json from django query not rendered

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, highcharts

I'm following this [article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/04/03/how-to-integrate-highcharts-js-with-django.html) to render highchart with json data from django query. However chart is not rendered but  I'm not getting any errors from Django or by the client when inspecting source. Appreciate if anyone can point the mistakes. Thank you in advance.

I'm using django 2.0 and python3.5

models.py

```
  PLATFORM = (
    ('ipcore','IPCORE'),
    ('metro','METRO E'),
    ('edge','EDGE'),
    ('access','ACCESS'),
    ('voice','VOICE'),
    ('system','SYSTEM'),
    ('iptv','IPTV'))

 class Contract(models.Model):
  vendor_name = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  contract_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
  partner_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, 
          blank=True, null=True)
  platform = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, 
          choices=PLATFORM)
```

views.py

```
 def json_example(request):
     return render(request, 'app/json_example.html')

 def chart_data(request):
     dataset=Contract.objects.all().values('platform').
         exclude(platform='').annotate(Sum('value')).order_by('value__sum')
     platform_name = dict()
     for platform_tuple in Contract.PLATFORM:
     platform_name[platform_tuple[0]] = platform_tuple[1]

     chart = {
         'chart': {'type': 'pie'},
         'title': {'text': 'Contract Value for Every platform'},
         'series': [{
               'name': 'Platform',
               'data': list(map(lambda row: {'name': 
                platform_name[row['platform']], 
               'y': row['value__sum']}, dataset))
          }]
     }
     return JsonResponse(chart)
```

urls.py

```
 url('json_example/', views.json_example, name='json_example'),
 url('json_example/data/', views.chart_data, name='chart_data'),
```

json_example.html

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Contract Inventory Highcharts Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container" data-url="{% url 'chart_data' %}"></div>
     <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
        $.ajax({
           url: $("#container").attr("data-url"),
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data) {
             Highcharts.chart("container", data);
           }
        });
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is the json data from dataset.

```
 [{"platform": "IPTV", "value__sum": "0.00"}, {"platform": "METRO E", "value__sum": "71372564.20"}, {"platform": "EDGE", "value__sum": "73867073.63"}, {"platform": "SYSTEM", "value__sum": "135465418.85"}, {"platform": "IPCORE", "value__sum": "467810178.41"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is the json data from dataset.

```
 [{"platform": "IPTV", "value__sum": "0.00"}, {"platform": "METRO E", "value__sum": "71372564.20"}, {"platform": "EDGE", "value__sum": "73867073.63"}, {"platform": "SYSTEM", "value__sum": "135465418.85"}, {"platform": "IPCORE", "value__sum": "467810178.41"}]
```

---

Your json data doesn't contain chart options. It should be something like this:

```
'{"title":{"text":"Title"},"series":[{"name":"Installation","data":[43934,52503,57177,69658,97031,119931,137133,154175]}]}'
```

What's more, you should parse json to js object before passing it to Highcharts constructor:

```
  <script>
    $.ajax({
       url: $("#container").attr("data-url"),
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {
         var chartData = JSON.parse(data);
         Highcharts.chart("container", chartData);
       }
    });
  </script>
```

**Check the example:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7zfyhnbr/

Comment: I was thinking that the data is sufficient for piechart. The example you showed is for line chart

Comment: after updated the script with parse json to js object, i got this error in js console: 
                                                                                                   
         highcharts.src.js:493 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: 
    www.highcharts.com/errors/16
    at Object.a.error (highcharts.src.js:493)
    at highcharts.src.js:63
    at highcharts.src.js:99
    at highcharts.src.js:20
    at highcharts.src.js:22      Any idea to solve this?

Comment: I showed you an example of chart properties - of course, you have to change them depending on what you want to achieve. This error means that you've loaded Highcharts twice. Are you sure you are loading it only once in the whole app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the data in such a way that it should match the highcharts ploting object. Please checkout the below code.

```js
data =  [
    {"platform": "IPTV", "value__sum": "0.00"},
    {"platform": "METRO E", "value__sum": "71372564.20"},
    {"platform": "EDGE", "value__sum": "73867073.63"},
    {"platform": "SYSTEM", "value__sum": "135465418.85"},
    {"platform": "IPCORE", "value__sum": "467810178.41"}];

x_axis_data = [];
y_axis_data = [];

for(index=0; index < data.length; index++) {
  item = data[index];
  x_axis_data.push(item['platform'])
  y_axis_data.push(parseFloat(item['value__sum']))
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
       text: 'learnbatta.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'X Value'
        },
        categories: x_axis_data
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Y Value'
        },
    },
    
    series: [{
        name: 'Curve',
        data: y_axis_data
    }]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to update your code like below

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
       url: $("#container").attr("data-url"),
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {
         var data = JSON.parse(data);
         x_axis_data = [];
         y_axis_data = [];

         for(index=0; index < data.length; index++) {
           item = data[index];
           x_axis_data.push(item['platform'])
           y_axis_data.push(parseFloat(item['value__sum']))
         }

         Highcharts.chart('container', {
            title: {
               text: 'learnbatta.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'X Value'
                },
                categories: x_axis_data
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Y Value'
                },
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Curve',
                data: y_axis_data
            }]
        });

       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how to update the code above with my existing template? or views?

Comment: @ji.sein updated the code check it. Accept the answer and give an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to solve it by updated my views.py using django rest API and my template accordingly. Here is my updated code:

views.py

```
  from rest_framework.views import APIView
  from rest_framework.response import Response

  class ChartView(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return render(request, 'app/charts.html')

  class ChartData(APIView):
     authentication_classes = []
     permission_classes = []

     def get(self, request, format=None):
        totalvendor= Contract.objects.all().values("vendor_name_id__name").
           annotate(Count("id")).order_by('-id__count')[:8]
        labels = totalvendor.values_list('vendor_name_id__name')
        default_items = totalvendor.values_list('id__count', flat=True)
        default_items = list(default_items)
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "default": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Pass an array from queryset to template and js

Here is my urls.py

```
 url(r'^chart/', views.ChartView.as_view(), name='chart'),
 url(r'^api/chart/data/$', ChartData.as_view(), name='chartdata'),
```

Here my code for charts.html

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
var defaultData = []
var labels = [];



$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default
        setChart()
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

function setChart(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("myChart2");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx2, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Value Contract for Platform',
            data: defaultData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title:{
            display:true,
            text:'Count Contract for Every Platform',
            fontSize:18,
            position:'top'
        },
        legend:{
            display:false,
            position:'right',
            labels:{
                fontColor:'#000'
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Count Contract for Platform',
            data: defaultData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}
// var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12' url-endpoint='{% url "chartdata" %}'>
        <h1>Data Presentation</h1>
        <div class=''>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Anyway thanks to those who answered my questions